# Is there any alternative of generate_series()function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am migrating structure of PostgreSQL to Oracle 12c but somewhere i am finding difficulties converting Generate_series function to oracle. is there any solution for this .

The code provided below i have used in postgresql.

```
SELECT (my_day - elapsed_my_day)
     INTO return_v
     FROM (select count(1) elapsed_my_day from
     generate_series(trunc(fromdate), trunc(todate) - 1, '1 day' interval) i;
```

What would be the proper syntax of `generate_series()` function in Oracle.

Comment: The following link shows an equivalent function for Oracle : http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/82/generate_series-an-oracle-implementation-in-light-of-sql-design-patterns

Comment: I don't see the reason to use `generate_series()` to begin with. As far as I can tell, in Postgres the above can be simplified to a simple subtraction of two dates: `todate::date - fromdate::date`

Comment: @Arnaud Be careful with that function as Oracle Spatial & Graph is a paid feature and its unclear whether use of a collection from that package would activate that feature and require licensing. There are other collections that could be used as the return value that are definitely freely available (like `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`).

Comment: @MT0 : Thanks for adding those warnings, I didn't think about that .

Comment: @arnaud but the syntax provided in link is for postgresql and not supporting oracle. eg.  RETURN CODESYS.centroid.t_numbers PIPELINED.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be counting the number of days between two dates and then subtracting that offset from another day. You don't need to generate a series and count it; just subtract from dates. You don't even need to use a `SQL` query, it can be purely written in PL/SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  return_v := m_day - ( TRUNC( to_date ) - 1 - TRUNC( from_date ) );
END;
```

Comment: "*You don't need to generate a series and count it; just subtract from dates*" which is true for Postgres as well